# no instance of overloaded function AddSnapshotListener matches the argument list

Tags: c++, firebase, winapi, google-cloud-firestore

i am trying to use Firebase cpp SDK in my win32 application. i used code from documentation

```
db->Collection("cities")
.WhereEqualTo("state", FieldValue::String("CA"))
.AddSnapshotListener([](const QuerySnapshot& snapshot, Error error) {
  if (error == Error::kErrorOk) {
    for (const DocumentChange& dc : snapshot.DocumentChanges()) {
      switch (dc.type()) {
        case DocumentChange::Type::kAdded:
          std::cout << "New city: "
                    << dc.document().Get("name").string_value() << '\n';
          break;
        case DocumentChange::Type::kModified:
          std::cout << "Modified city: "
                    << dc.document().Get("name").string_value() << '\n';
          break;
        case DocumentChange::Type::kRemoved:
          std::cout << "Removed city: "
                    << dc.document().Get("name").string_value() << '\n';
          break;
      }
    }
  } else {
    std::cout << "Listen failed: " << error << '\n';
  }
});
```

from : https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/query-data/listen#c++_4

but it gives me following error:

```
    no instance of overloaded function "firebase::firestore::Query::AddSnapshotListener" matches the argument list
```

is there a way to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/cpp/class/firebase/firestore/query#addsnapshotlistener) says the callback for `Query::AddSnapshotListener` takes 3 arguments, whereas your implementation accepts only two.

The proper signature would be:

```
.AddSnapshotListener([](const QuerySnapshot& snapshot, Error error, const std::string& error_msg) {
 // ...
});
```

**Edit**:

The inconsistency between the code in your link and the offical API reference weirded me out a bit, so I dug a bit more. It looks like the third argument was added about [8 months ago](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-cpp-sdk/blame/8f3e19226639a3b91e5d879cdf5f3d867dbf8db4/firestore/src/include/firebase/firestore/query.h#L622), and the user guide just hasn't been update to reflect that yet.

That's really unfortunate.

Comment: @Klaffy I updated the answer with some more info as to what I think caused the confusion in the first place.

Comment: yes i also see, we should some how let them know these problem. btw thank you for help